# How can I pass multiple variables to a function?

Tags: arduino-uno, functions

Using the FastLED library, I want to light up multiple lights at once.

Currently I am passing in just one light to the function.

```
spell( int LEDNumber )
{
  FastLED.clear();
  leds[LEDNumber] = CRGB (255,255,255); //white
  FastLED.show();
  time = 500;
  delay(t);
}
```

I would like to pass in more than just 1 light at a time.

Comment: This is really a basic C/C++ programming question, not an Arduino question. In any case, I'm glad you were able to figure it out.

Comment: @DuncanC There is indeed a sort of no-man's land there, since Arduino does restrict how you can use C++, especially vis-a-vis memory restrictions.  I am not sure that I would be so strict with Joshua, or anyone for the matter.

Comment: Tony, yes, there are some gray areas, but this is a programming 101 question for C/C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may create a `struct` with "x" elements, one for each LED:

```
struct ArrayOfBooleans {
   bool array[4];
};

ArrayOfBooleans myOutputArray;
myOutputArray.array[0] = true;
myOutputArray.array[1] = true;
myOutputArray.array[2] = false;
myOutputArray.array[3] = true;

lightEmUp(myOutputArray);

void lightEmUp(ArrayOfBooleans myOutputArray) {
   bool isFirstLightOn = myOutputArray.array[0];
   // etc
}
```

NoTE: If you run into `Exception 9` issues (using this logic on another board), please check [this answer to another post](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/67450/30341)

Comment: Wonderful answer. Way better than what I found. Thanks!

Comment: I just recently ran into this issue and this was the solution that i implemented.  keeps things cleaner, as well as making upgrading (adding or removing parameters) easier..  tks for accepting.

Comment: Exception 9 on Uno?

Comment: why the struct? it is useless and will be copied as function parameter. you can pass the array as parameter

Comment: you could do that, but a struct may have other data as well - such as multiple arrays for multiple dimensions of parameters.  such as other parameters.  a struct as a class is far from useless, especially if your development is method oriented.

Comment: i find your spamming rude and abusive in abstract and have flagged you for it, @Juraj.  I am not hard of reading, there is no point in sequentially writing the same rude comment.

Answer (score 1):

Easier than I thought. Found it while reading the docs. Imagine that. :)

To pass in multiple variables, just separate them with a comma.

Docs: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/FunctionDeclaration

Relevant code:

```
int myMultiplyFunction(int x, int y){
  int result;
  result = x * y;
  return result;
}
```